# D3.js - Autoresize of y axis labels

Tags: javascript, d3.js, yaxis

I created a chart with D3.js as following which is displayed on the left (null margin) of my webpage but the y axis' labels are not displayed completely :

[image]

How to avoid this and show the complete labels (10,000 for example) ? Do I have to increase the size of the SVG ? Decrease the one of the text ? Would you have some piece of code please ?

Do you need further information ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

It is likely your labels are starting outside the viewable area of the svg element.  You can apply, for example an `attr('transform','translate(x,y)')` where `x` is the horizontal translation, and `y`, the vertical (likely `y=0` in this case).

It is also possible and perhaps preferable to set the domain of the plot to start a bit further to the right, e.g.,

```
d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(min,max)
  .range(x1,x2)
```

again where `x1` is your the pixel at which `min` appears and `x2` is the pixel value for `max`